# Requests CookieJar empty even thought the page have it

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I'm on Python 3.5.1, using requests, the relevant part of the code is as follows:

```
req = requests.post(self.URL, data={"username": username, "password": password}) 
self.cookies = {"MOODLEID1_": req.cookies["MOODLEID1_"], "MoodleSession": req.cookies["MoodleSession"]}
```

`self.URL` has the correct page, and the POST is working as intended, I did some print to check that, and it passed.

My output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/.../main.py", line 14, in <module>
    m.login('first.last', 'pa$$w0rd!')
  File "D:\...\moodle2.py", line 14, in login
    self.cookies = {"MOODLEID1_": req.cookies["MOODLEID1_"], "MoodleSession": req.cookies["MoodleSession"]}
  File "D:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 287, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "D:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 345, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='MOODLEID1_', domain=None, path=None"
```

I'm trying to debug during runtime to check what `req.cookies` has. But what I get is surprising, at least for me. If you put a breakpoint on `self.cookies = {...}` and run `[(c.name, c.value, c.domain) for c in req.cookies]` I get an empty list, like there isn't any cookie in there.

The site does send cookies, checking with a Chrome extension, I found 2, "MOODLEID1_" and "MoodleSession", so why I'm not getting them?

Comment: What does `req.headers` show was sent by the server? Are there any Set-Cookie headers there? If not, then the server didn't send any cookies.

Comment: I didn't find any `Set-Cookie` on `req.headers`, but on Chrome I can clearly see both cookies using an extension. Why can't I see them on my script?

Comment: Cookies are always sent from server to client with a `Set-Cookie` header. That the cookies are there in Chrome does not mean they were set by the URL you are POSTing to now; they could have been set by a *different* URL. You'll need to find what URL the server issues `Set-Cookie` headers with.

Comment: Hum OK, thanks. Please, post it so I can mark an correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The response doesn't appear to contain any cookies. Look for one or more `Set-Cookie` headers in `req.headers`.

Cookies stored in a browser are there because a response included a `Set-Cookie` header for each of those cookies. You'll have to find what response the server sets those cookies with; apparently it is not *this* response.

If you need to retain those cookies (once set) across requests, do use a [`requests.Session()` object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects); this'll retain any cookies returned by responses and send them out again as appropriate with new requests.

Comment: Thanks. `requests.Session()` worked like a charm. Indeed, those cookies were from another URL.